# How to show bullet for 2nd level link in current navigation?

Tags: 2013, navigation, css

My current navigation is like below:

Page1
  - Link1
  - Link2

I want to show "arrow" for Page1 and "bullets" for "Link1" and "Link2".

I am able to do the "arrow" part using the following code:

```
.ms-noList ul, .ms-noList ol, .ms-noList
{
    list-style-image:url('arrow.gif');
}
```

This shows arrow along with "Page1" link. But problem is it also shows same arrow for all sublinks too. I want to show a separate bullet image for sub links.

How do I do that?

Comment: please provide class details generated for the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your markup looks something like this:

```
<div class="ms-noList">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Page 1
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Link 1
                </li>
                <li>
                    Link 2
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

If you just define the list-style-image for both types of lists, you can overwrite the first one, due to cascading:

```
.ms-noList ul {
    list-style-image: url('arrow.gif');
}

.ms-noList ul ul {
    list-style-image: url('bullet.gif');
}

/* or */

.ms-noList ul ul {
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```